# How not to explicitly specify members for which the name automatically match up?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am using AutoMapper 9.0 and in the example below, I am mapping a `Person` to a `People` Object.

Because 1 member differs from Person to People (Person has **Sfx** while People has **Suffix**), I have to specifically map the rest of the properties that would otherwise automatically match up.

Is there a way to not specify them but for them to still be mapped ?

```
    configurationExpression.CreateMap<JsonRequest, XmlRequest>()
                .ForMember(
                    dest => dest.People,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new People
                    {
                        FirstName = src.Person.FirstName,
                        MiddleName = src.Person.MiddleName,
                        LastName = src.Person.LastName,
                        Suffix = src.Person.Sfx
                    }));
```

Comment: I think the syntax you're looking for is something like `ForMember(d => d.Suffix, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Sfx))` - or maybe the other way round, it's been a while since I used AutoMapper.

Comment: Why is your mapping configuration not explicitly specifying `Person` and `People`?  Not sure why you are basing it on `JsonRequest` and `XmlRequest` - kinda broad.  Might be inefficient too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the [documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html), you should be able to achieve this by defining separate mappings for your `OutterClass` and `InnerClass`:

> ```
> var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
>     cfg.CreateMap<OuterSource, OuterDest>();
>     cfg.CreateMap<InnerSource, InnerDest>();
> });
> ```

Have you tried something like this?

```
configurationExpression.CreateMap<Person, People>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Suffix, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.sfx))
    .ReverseMap(); 

configurationExpression.CreateMap<JsonRequest, XmlRequest>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.People, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Person))
    .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a 'nested mapping' at all, so there is no 'outer' and 'inner' here - it looks like a simple A-B mapping with a different property name..

Comment: I am not sure if I follow... to me `People` is a nested type inside `XmlRequest`

Comment: @stuartd OP is basing config mapping on types `JsonRequest` and `XmlRequest` which appear to be containers for `Person` and `People`.  OP's `XmlRequest` at least has a `People` property so it seems there is indeed an outer an inner.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini I will try that and will let you know. In this case, what is the purpose for .ReverseMap() ?

Comment: `ReverseMap` is for mapping the other way around, i.e. `XmlRequest` to `JsonRequest`... if you don't need the it, you can just remove the `ReverseMap`